# Iterate filename with number

Tags: python, file-io, iterator

I want to create around a 100 files on the disk with each having the names `1.txt`, `2.txt` and so forth. I have tried different combinations of `open(str(i).txt,w+)`, `open(i+'.txt', 'w+')` but none seem to work out.

Also these files do not exist on the disk before being created by Python. How to I go about solving these issues?

Answer (score 3):

To create a new string, you have to concatenate two strings:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    with open(str(i) + '.txt', 'w') as fobj:
        # do what you want here with the file object
        fobj.write('foo\n')
```

In case you need more complicate filenames, the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method can come in handy. The equivalent of the above would be: `'{0}.txt'.format(i)`. I also think it's more readable.

As for your attempts, the first one couldn't possibly work because the `.txt` part would have cause Python to look for a string *method* named `txt`, which does not exist. Also the second argument of `open()` should be a string, so that's an error as well. In the second attempt, which was almost correct you only forgot to convert `i` to a string. As I said above, you cannot concatenate a *number* with a *string*.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm. I needed ".txt" as suggested by @hlt to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
open(str(i) + ".txt", "w+")
```

for each `i` to create the file with the right number. Of course, you can also use *format strings*:

```
open("%d.txt" % i, "w+") # Old-style format strings, discouraged
```

or

```
open("{0!s}.txt".format(i), "w+") # New-style format strings from Python 2.6 onwards
```

Comment: Just to note that explicitly specifying `!s` as the conversion flag isn't necessary here...